Angular Error TS2792 and changes in Angular Local Version and Node support
I am trying to build a project that looks like this:

This is the Angular CLI and Node versions that I have installed before:

and of course my package.json: 
I am trying to get this running but, after awhile when I run $ ng serve it first steps on its Building Phase. Soon after that I get this error and my Angular CLI version changes up to 13.2.4. This project was related to a Udemy Unit Testing course that I've been trying to do but couldn't do to this. Any hints on how to solve this? Thank you



Trying deleting your node_modules folder and then try issuing a npm i --legacy-peer-deps command once, then try ng serve

@DavidR It is giving me same error. my tsconfig.json is an empty file (it was given that way)
